# Win32 - Fastest way to read desktop pixels

Tags: c++, windows, windows-ce, gdi

I have been tasked with writing an (unmanaged c++ win32) application to show the current desktop of a Windows CE 5.0 across a network to another computer.  The customer demands original code, and has rejected some VNC code I found.

I have something working, but I have a throughput bottleneck.  The only way I could find to get the pixels of the screen was to create a DIB with CreateDibSection, and use Bitblt to copy the pixels to a buffer.   After profiling my code, I find that on Windows 7, 60% of the CPU time my app uses is spend in Bitblt.  On Windows CE, it is more like 80%.
   It doesn't seem to matter if I use 32bits, 24bits or 16 bits per pixel.

My question is:
    Is there a better(faster) way to ready the entire desktop pixels than CreateDibSection and BitBlt?  In my application, it will run on specific hardware, so I do not need device independence.

Comment: First off try a device dependent bitmap?

Comment: Have you tried using a really big magnifying glass?

Comment: Would a screenshot on demand do, or is there an expectation of being able to watch video at 30fps, or somewhere in between? It seems a bit daft to ask for the functionality of RDP or VNC to be replicated unless you have a very large budget and a lot of time.

Comment: Blitting to a DIB section will almost certainly involve a pixel format conversion.  Try using a compatible bitmap (CreateCompatibleDC and CreateCompatibleBitmap) and blit from the screen to that.

Answer (score 2):

Is the request to have original code motivated by legal issues? Microsoft provides the code of the cerdisp applications under the shared source licence and this does exactly what you are asking.
At least you can check that code to understand which APIs it uses to capture the screen image.